# Migrate filter_format with embedded_data plugin

Tags: migrations, 9

I'm trying to migrate filter_format from d6 to d9, I'm using embedded_data 'cause migrate_drupal doesn't work with D6; so I'm trying to do it in another way.

This is my yml file.

```yml
id: project_filter_format
label: Filter format configuration
migration_group: project_filter_format
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 6
  - Configuration
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    -
      format: 1
      name: Filtered HTML
      cache: 1
      roles:
      filters:
        -
          module: filter
          delta: 0
          weight: -10
          settings:
            -
              fid: 55
  ids:
    -
      fid
process:
  format:
    plugin: machine_name
    source: name
  name: name
  cache: cache
  filters:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: filters
    key: '@id'
    process:
      id:
        # If the filter ID cannot be mapped, it will be passed through
        # unchanged because the bypass flag is set. The filter_id plugin
        # will flatten the input value and default it to filter_null (the
        # fallback filter plugin ID) if the flattened input value is not
        # a valid plugin ID.
        plugin: filter_id
        source:
          - module
          - delta
        bypass: true
        map:
          filter:
            - filter_html
            - filter_autop
            - filter_url
            - filter_htmlcorrector
            - filter_html_escape
      settings:
        plugin: filter_settings
        source: settings
      status:
        plugin: default_value
        default_value: true
destination:
  plugin: entity:filter_format
  no_stub: true
```

I have check Drupal\filter\Plugin\migrate\source\d6\FilterFormat.php to try to understand if the row it has the correct structure.

```yml
    -
      format: 1
      name: Filtered HTML
      cache: 1
      roles:
      filters:
        -
          module: filter
          delta: 0
          weight: -10
          settings:
            -
              fid: 55
```

But I'm not sure if it's the problem or is another.

This is the error I get.

> Migration failed with source plugin exception: '0' is defined as a source ID but has no value. in /var/www/html/web/core/modules/migrate/src/Row.php line 108

I'm not sure if the problem it's de data_rows, the source IDs definition, or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the source ID property (`fid`) does not exist. As the file is structured, only the following could be used as such: `format`, `name`, `cache`, `roles`, `filters`. By the way `roles` is not mapped nor used while you process the row.

You could just do the following:

```
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  data_rows:
    - id: 1
      format: 1
      name: Filtered HTML
      cache: 1
      roles:
      filters:
        - module: filter
          delta: 0
          weight: -10
          settings:
            -
              fid: 55
  ids:
    id:
      type: string
```